# VMWare and webpack hot reload

Tags: vmware, webpack

I have setup a VMWare ubuntu virutal machine for development purposes. I ssh/vim in my vm and develop React/babel/webpack projects.

My webpack doesn't reload every time I save a file. It is not consistent. When I use my host operating system, it works perfectly.

Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there seems to be issue [with timestamps and virtual machines](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/425).

I have good result by adding these params to the the webpack der server:

```
{
      watchOptions: {
                aggregateTimeout: 300,
                poll: true
      }
}
```

Comment: If anybody having the issue with high CPU using this, try with different numbers for the poll starting at 1000 I suggest. My config `poll: 3000` for 3 seconds. Not amazing but works.